# Claims not persisited

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, adal

I have a MVC (with AAD auth) application and want to persist some data in the auth cookie. In my home controller I have following:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity;

        claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("test01","sada"));
```

...

After the page has loaded I refreh the page (F5) and in the debugger I can see that the claim is not persisted. Any clues what I am doing wrong? Shouldnt data be persisted?

Answer (score 1):

With your code to add a claim in a controller ,the new claim won't be set in the cookie and you will not see it in the next request.

If you are using the ASP.NET OWIN middleware and want to add custom attribute for your user ,OnTokenValidated notification offers you the chance to modify the ClaimsIdentity obtained from the incoming token . Please read [this blog](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/08/26/augmenting-the-set-of-incoming-claims-with-the-openid-connect-and-oauth2-middleware-in-katana-3-x/) for explanation and code sample . If you are using ASP.NET Core , you could refer to [my reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44897107/5751404) for code sample .